Excel VBA: Select top k numbers from a range and compute an average
I need to select top k numbers from an Excel range (column) and calculate their mean.
In Excel it looks easy:
=AVERAGE(LARGE(<<range>>,SEQUENCE(<<k>>)))
When using a range containing numbers from 1 to 10, and a k of 3, I get a correct result of 9 (an average of 8, 9 and 10).
Where I'm stuck, is trying to do the same in a UDF in Excel VBA.
A simple conversion of Excel functions to VBA does not work:
Public Function top_k_average(ByVal rng As Range)
top_k_average = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Average(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sequence(3)))
End Function

Using this is an Excel cell returns a #VALUE error
=top_k_average(<<range>>)
It looks to me that WorksheetFunction.Large does work with k which is not just a scalar.
Any hints very much appreciated - thanks!

Try this way:
Public Function top_k_average(ByVal rng As Range)
    top_k_average = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Average(Application.Large(rng, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sequence(3)))
End Function

WorksheetFunction.Large requires single value as a second argument.
But you can use an older version Application.Large instead.

Isn't Application.Large just the late-bound version, and not "older"?

I don't know this, but I do know that before the WorksheetFunction object was introduced, you could use the Application.FunctionName version and it works on an "extended" principle, that is, it handles arrays not only single values (when function typically expects single values) and handles errors in a different way.

@MGonet: Thank you! I would have never guessed - I thought Application.[fun] is just a shortcut for the longer Excel.Worsheet... syntax.
Works smoothly now!
